# Hinge Joint 2D stops to work properly when the game resets

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I having trouble with a simple hingejoint2d who consists in a simple chain with a box attached to. It works fine until the game restart, when the game restart the box fall from the chain, but the chain continue in the place. I have no idea whats causing it. heres the code to reset the objects.

````
    private Quaternion startRot;
    private Vector3 startLocalScale;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private HingeJoint2D hj;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        startPos = transform.position;
        startRot = transform.rotation;
        startLocalScale = transform.localScale;
        hj = GetComponent<HingeJoint2D>();
        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() != null)
        {
            rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    public void ResetObjects()
    {
        transform.position = startPos;
        transform.rotation = startRot;
        transform.localScale = startLocalScale;
        if (hj != null)
            return;


        if (rb != null)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        }

    }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be accessing an objects transform directly, if you're using a rigidbody, let the rigidbody component do the work! Otherwise things tend to get a little messy.

I ran into this issue today, and I used limits on the joint to get around this.

[image]

Enable Use limits. Then you can edit the constraints as you need.

```
using UnityEngine;

    public class Example : MonoBehaviour
    {
        void Start()
        {
            // Set the hinge limits for a door.
            HingeJoint hinge = GetComponent<HingeJoint>();

            JointLimits limits = hinge.limits;
            limits.min = 0;
            limits.bounciness = 0;
            limits.bounceMinVelocity = 0;
            limits.max = 90;
            hinge.limits = limits;
            hinge.useLimits = true;
        }
    }
```

source: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HingeJoint-limits.html

Comment: Thanks! I will try to fix that and see what happens.